# Upload the web site into the server

Tags: html

I can upload the web pages which is in html to the server and after uploading the link for that is
www.dhtc.lk/about_us.html

But I need to display it as www.dhtc.lk instead of above name and please guide me how to do this and my hostname is dhtc.lk

Please send me the solution for this.
Thank you

Comment: Honestly no idea what you are asking, can you be clearer in what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to get / to point to /about_us.html?

Comment: Is it me, or does that white background make the website's banner advertise a criminal-like organization ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename `about_us.html` to `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Rename `about_us.html` to `index.html`.

`index.html` is the first HTML file the server shows when loading a folder (in this case, the root folder, or `/`).

Comment: @Bang and @Blender thank you for your answers and now its working like that, but can I do multiple pages like this

Comment: Sure. Just make folders for them, like `/about/`, and put the HTML file in there like this `/about/index.html`. Now, when a person visits http://www.dhtc.lk/about/, they get the about page.

Answer (score 0):

Now sure what exactly you want but you can add a welcome file to the web.xml like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>about_us.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: What server is this for?

Answer (score 0):

To get your host to be coming up with www.dhtc.lk, you need to add a DNS entry to point www.dhtc.lk to the same host. Talk to your ISP to get this done.

Also, had a look at your site and looks like you have created each page in a separate directory. You need to save each page as a simple .html file and put all of these in the root directory of your web server. I recommend you read a bit more on web hosting.

Comment: I assume root directory is public_html directory or www directory and can please explain me the meaning of "DNS entry to point www.dhtc.lk".

Comment: DNS stands for Domain Name Service. If you talk to the guys at LKNIC or your ISP, they will know what this means. I worked for LKNIC long time back.

Comment: The root directory will depend on what your web server is and whether it is a shared host etc. Best thing would be for you to talk to someone who knows about this and get their help. I used to help a lot of people like you while I was at LKNIC.